# how does compareTo and compare work?

Tags: java

I know that compare and `compareTo` returns an `int` value.

For example:

```
Returns
0 if a equal b
-1 if a < b
+1 if a > b
```

`sort` method makes a call to either `compareTo` or `compare()` methods. But how does `sort` method arranges the `list` when compare or `compareTo` returns a `int` value. What is background scenario running after a `compare` or `compareTo` returns an int value to sort?how does `sort` method makes use of int values(`-1` or `0` or `1`) returned to it from `compare` and `compareTo`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm or if you want java specific: [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

Answer (score 28):

If the two elements (a,b) being compared are already in the right order, `compare(a, b)` and `a.compareTo(b)` both return a value that is `<= 0`, so nothing has to happen.

If they aren't in the right order, the return value is `> 0`, indicating that they must be interchanged.

Comment: +1 Best answer IMO, considering you *actually* answered the OP's question as opposed to just copying and pasting docs.

Answer (score 4):

General case sorting algorithms are based on comparisons.  If you compare between `a` and `b` - there are exactly 3 possibilities: `a == b`, `a > b`, `a < b`.

The `compare()` or `compareTo()` method provides exactly this information.

Now, to use this information we have designed numerous [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), starting with naive [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), and some are more advances such as [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Each providing a bit different approach to the sorting problem.

Java chose the [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) algorithm for its sorting implementation.

As an exercise, you can design your own<sup>1</sup> sorting algorithm. Can you find the maximum element of an array using the `compare()` method? when you found it where should it be? what should you do next?

---

(1) Well, think of it by yourself, but it already exists, actually :)

Answer (score 2):

Read [this document](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html):

- `a.compareTo(b)`:
  Comparable interface. Compares values and returns an int which tells if the values compare less than, equal, or greater than.
  If your class objects have a natural order, implement the Comparable interface and define this method. All Java classes that have a natural ordering implement this (String, Double, BigInteger, ...).
- `compare(a, b)`:
  Comparator interface. Compares values of two objects. This is implemented as part of the Comparator interface, and the typical use is to define one or more small utility classes that implement this, to pass to methods such as sort() or for use by sorting data structures such as TreeMap and TreeSet. You might want to create a Comparator object for the following:

  - Multiple comparisons. To provide several different ways to sort something. For example, you might want to sort a Person class by name, ID, age, height, ... You would define a Comparator for each of these to pass to the sort() method.
  - System class To provide comparison methods for classes that you have no control over. For example, you could define a Comparator for Strings that compared them by length.
  - Strategy pattern To implement a Strategy pattern, which is a situation where you want to represent an algorithm as an object that you can pass as a parameter, save in a data structure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, these implementations of compare() method would help you understand it better.

```
public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2)
{
 Integer I1 = (Integer)obj1; // typecasting object type into integer type
 Integer I2 = (Integer)obj2; // same as above ..
 // 1.
 return I1.compareTo(I2); // ascending order [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
 // 2.
 return -I1.compareTo(I2); // descending order [20, 15, 10, 5, 0]
 // 3.
 return I2.compareTo(I1); // descending order [20, 15, 10, 5, 0]
 // 4.
 return -I2.compareTo(I1); // ascending order [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
 // 5.
 return +1; // insertion order [10, 0, 15, 5, 20, 20]
 // 6.
 return -1; // reverse of insertion order [20, 20, 5, 15, 0, 10]
 // 7.
 return 0; // only first element [10]
}
```

[How compare() method works in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-compare-method-works-in-java/)